# How to infer type of callback parameters for typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, callback

I am trying to add typescript to my code and I do not seem to find how to infer some types. more precisely parameters of a callback.

```
Item.find({},(err, items) => {...} //missing type for callback parameters
```

"Item" is a Model from mongoose.

As you can see in the doc below, nothing specify the type of the callback parameters :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find

Am I supposed to just put "any" as a type ? Or is there some way I am missing out to find it?

Comment: Mongoose should have its own types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by declaring an interface for the schema I was using.

```
interface IItem{...}
const itemSchema = new Schema<IItem> (...)
const Item = model<IItem>("Item", itemSchema)
```

So for the solution being :

```
Item.find({}, (err: String, items: Array<IItem>){...}
```

It was explained in the doc :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html